# Are there any "writing prompts for programmers" sites?

Tags: coding-style

One proven strategy for creative writers to get something flowing is to use writing prompts ([one prompts site--mouse over a number to see a prompt](http://www.creativewritingprompts.com/)). The immediate output of writing to a prompt may not be particularly valuable, but it gets juices flowing.

Are there any "programming prompts sites" designed to help the visitor get to an idea of a project and get into that hacking, tinkering state where you make one enhancement and then another enhancement presents itself?

Comment: Providing help 3 years later... But you should check out http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer

Comment: Providing help 4 years later... But you should check out [http://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammingPrompts/](http://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammingPrompts/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this sounds like a random startup generator http://www.ykombinator.com/ - I've seen similar sites to the ykombinator one but can't find them right now.

Comment: Actually, notwithstanding the sarcasm in ykombinator, this looks significantly better than nothing for what I had in mind.